# Meson build of pango static library does not link in dependencies

Tags: linux, cairo, pkg-config, meson-build, pango

I'm trying to build pango (https://github.com/GNOME/pango) as a static library. It is using Meson build which I'm not familiar with. Anyway, the compile steps succeed, but linking fails with a lot of undefined references to libfontconfig, libpixman-1 and libpng. These are all present and can be found via PKG_CONFIG_PATH. The preceding build of cairo (https://cairographics.org/snapshots/cairo-1.17.8.tar.xz) seemed to succeed.

I'm trying to build pango via

```
meson setup --reconfigure --buildtype release --strip --prefix $INSTALL_ROOT/pango --libdir $INSTALL_ROOT/pango/lib --default-library static $BUILD_ROOT\pango $DOWNLOAD_ROOT/pango
meson compile -C $BUILD_ROOT/pango
meson install -C $BUILD_ROOT/pango
```

and the errors are:

```
[361/445] Linking target subprojects/harfbuzz/util/hb-view
FAILED: subprojects/harfbuzz/util/hb-view
g++  -o subprojects/harfbuzz/util/hb-view subprojects/harfbuzz/util/hb-view.p/hb-view.cc.o -L/home/test/Intermediates/ThirdParty/BuildProducts/zlib/lib -I/home/test/Intermediates/ThirdParty/BuildProducts/zlib/include -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-O1 -fPIC -pthread -Wl,--start-group subprojects/harfbuzz/src/libharfbuzz.a /home/test/Intermediates/ThirdParty/BuildProducts/freetype/lib/libfreetype.a /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /home/test/Intermediates/ThirdParty/BuildProducts/cairo/lib/libcairo.a /home/test/Intermediates/ThirdParty/BuildProducts/glib/lib/libglib-2.0.a -lm /home/test/Intermediates/ThirdParty/BuildProducts/glib/lib/libpcre2-8.a -Wl,--end-group
/bin/ld: /home/test/Intermediates/ThirdParty/BuildProducts/cairo/lib/libcairo.a(cairo-image-compositor.o): in function `lerp':
cairo-image-compositor.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `pixman_image_composite32'
/bin/ld: cairo-image-compositor.c:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `pixman_image_composite32'
/bin/ld: /home/test/Intermediates/ThirdParty/BuildProducts/cairo/lib/libcairo.a(cairo-image-compositor.o): in function `_mono_finish_unbounded_spans':
...
/bin/ld: /home/test/Intermediates/ThirdParty/BuildProducts/cairo/lib/libcairo.a(cairo-png.o): in function `write_png':
cairo-png.c:(.text+0x304): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
/bin/ld: cairo-png.c:(.text+0x31a): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
...
```

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: Static libraries cannot link or reference other libraries. You need to specify all dependencies when you link the final executable.

Comment: Random, non-helpful guess would be that this is really some kind of problem with the `pkg-config` file that cairo provides. I guess this file just does not contain the necessary information for static linking (i.e. that cairo depends on pixman). WIth a shared library this information is not necessary in the pkg-config file and thus can just be left out. I don't have any good suggestions what to do about this.

Comment: Thanks @UliSchlachter, that's what I thought myself too. Alas, this thing used to work earlier (with much older versions of all libraries, i.e. no meson) and I do not see any substantial difference between the cairo.pc files, in both cases pixman only appears on the Requires.private line. I have to admit I'm not very familiar with pkg-config either.

Comment: Yes, when I added the -L and -l options for pixman, fontconfig, libpng and libxml2 to the Libs line of cairo.pc, the pango build now succeeded.

Comment: Now suspecting that pango build does not call `pkg-config --static` when invoked by `meson setup --default-library static`. It's still building static libpangocairo-1.0.a so it looks like it recognizes `--default-library static`, just does not invoke pkg-config correctly.